# Why do I get the error message "Fcinit fatal vloopback not found" whenever I boot?

Tags: 10.10, boot, fonts

I get this message whenever I boot. It has something to do with the fontconfig/cache. Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

FcInit - initialize fontconfig library who is provided by libfontconfig1-dev_2.3.2-1.1ubuntu12_i386.

FcInit, loads  the  default configuration file and the fonts referenced therein
and sets the default configuration to  that  result.   Returns  whether
this  process  succeeded  or  not.   If  the  default configuration has
already been loaded, this routine does nothing and returns FcTrue.

So, do a force install to libfontconfig1-dev_2.3.2-1.1ubuntu12_i386.